# How to draw a lines from one element to another in dynamic way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, canvas

[image]

Im trying to implement lines which would connect each div in this way.
What would be the best way to implement this design. The problem is that it could be N number of  div boxes since it's ng-repeat.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated! 
thanks

Comment: Put a canvas behind the elements and draw some lines on it

Comment: Solid color divs for the bars. Transparent divs with the left and bottom border defined to make the 'L' shape. Clever grid positioning to bring it all together. Or canvas if the elements do not need any event handlers. Or SVG if you want a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to be working, you'll still have to figure out a couple of things (remove the first line, different coloring, ...)

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(-5px);
  position: relative;
}

.row:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```